# Backend - Queue for Excel Macro

Tags: excel, vba, docker, flask, redis

I have a really big problem about finding the right architecture and  for the following;

1. I have a VBA Macro which retrieves the parameters from one sheet, calculates an algorithm (it takes time) and outputs the result in the another sheet.
2. I need to create a backend (could be Flask or Nodejs) which is connected a kind of queue (Redis or RabbitMQ) which gets the parameters from Frontend (or HTTP Client) as POST request, then saves this parameters into the queue. After that a worker function should get them asynchronously run the excel macro and sends result back.
3. Its not obligatory but I want to use Docker ( I am open any other suggestions).

So I have tried this solution with xlwings, redis and flask with docker but it did not work.

- If I use docker containers for Windows, I can not use Redis.
- If I use docker containers for Linux, I can not use pywin32, I can only use xlwings library but it is not supported to save some parameters. [Limitation of Xlwings](https://docs.xlwings.org/en/latest/pro/reader.html#limitations)
- I can add the another macro to excel to make http request to rabbitmq [As Shown here](https://funprojects.blog/2019/11/08/rabbitmq-rest-api/) but I dont know how to keep this macro running in Docker container

Can you give me a better architecture or solution?

Thank you.

```
    # ----------------- Flask (main.py) -------------
import os
from flask import Flask, make_response, request, jsonify
from redis import Redis
from rq import Queue
from server.excel_worker import run_excel_macro

app = Flask(__name__)
redis = Redis('redis', 6379)
q = Queue('excel_tasks', connection=redis)

@app.route('/add-task', methods=['POST'])
def create_task():
    json = request.json
    absolute_path = os.path.dirname(__file__)
    filename = os.path.join('excel-file', 'excel-file.xlsm')
    full_path = os.path.join(absolute_path, filename)
    task = q.enqueue(run_excel_macro, full_path, 'Macro1', json)
    data = {'message': 'Task Created', 'task_id': task.get_id()}
    return make_response(jsonify(data), 201)

@app.route("/tasks/<task_id>", methods=["GET"])
def get_status(task_id):
    task = q.fetch_job(task_id)
    if task.is_queued:
        response_object = {
            "data": {
                "task_id": task.get_id(),
                "task_status": task.get_status(),
                "task_result": task.return_value(),
            },
        }
        return jsonify(response_object)
    if task.is_started:
        response_object = {
            "data": {
                "task_id": task.get_id(),
                "task_status": task.get_status(),
                "task_result": task.return_value(),
            },
        }
        return jsonify(response_object)
    elif task.is_finished:
        return jsonify({'result': task.return_value()})
    else:
        return jsonify({"status": "error"})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')

# ----------------- Excel Worker-------------
def run_excel_macro(filename, macro_name, variable_dict):
   # Setting some parameters from variables
    name = variable_dict['name']
    surname = variable_dict['surname']
    # Set Some more
    # Run Excel macro using xlwings
    xw.App().visible = False
    wb = xw.Book(filename)
    sheet1 = wb.sheets[0]
    # Write some values in Excel Sheet
     sheet1.range('A1').value = name
     sheet1.range('A2').value = surname
    macro = wb.macro(macro_name)
    # Run Macro 
    macro()
     # Get Calculation of Macro and send result
    result = {
      ... calculation result
    }
    wb.save()
    wb.close()
    return result

# -----------------Dockerfile-------------
FROM python:3.9
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
EXPOSE 5000
CMD ["python", "main.py"]
# -----------------Docker-Compose-------------
version: '3.8'

services:
  redis:
    image: redis:latest
    ports:
      - '6379:6379'
    volumes:
      - ./redis:/redis

  flask-app:
    image: app-image
    container_name: flask-app
    restart: always
    build: app
    ports:
      - '5000:5000'
    depends_on:
      - redis

  worker:
    image: app-image:latest
    depends_on:
      - redis
    command: rq worker excel_tasks --url redis://redis:6379
    links:
      - redis
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trouble of running Excel inside a VM or a Container might not be worth it. If your code works well on your machine and it doesn't need to be on a server, you can probably stop here.

Also, since this is a question about architecture, you don't need to use a mixed architecture to make POST requests, VBA has that capability already. For instance, you could use the `WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1` object from the Microsoft WinHTTP Services, version 5.1 Library.

For Example:

```vb
    Dim TCRequestItem As Object
    Set TCRequestItem = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
    
    Dim Endpoint As String
    Endpoint = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts"
    
    Dim PayLoad As String
    PayLoad = "{ ""context"" : { ""priority"" : ""REALTIME"", ""properties"" : [ ] }, ""inputPerson"" : { ""type"" : ""NaturalInputPerson"", ""personName"" : { ""nameFields"" : [ { ""string"" : ""John"", ""fieldType"" : ""GIVENNAME""}, {""string"" : ""Doe"", ""fieldType"" : ""SURNAME""} ]}, ""gender"" : ""UNKNOWN"" }}"
    
    Dim Token As String
    Token = "FakeToken"
    
    With TCRequestItem
        .Open "POST", Endpoint, False
        .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
        .setRequestHeader "Accept", "application/json"
        .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.111 Safari/537.36"
        .setRequestHeader "Authorization", "Bearer " & Token
        .Send PayLoad
    End With
    
    Debug.Print TCRequestItem.responseText
```

You can also have a main workbook (parent) that controls the queue and make those POST requests while the other workbook (child) is executing the algorithm.

```vb
    Dim ExcelApp As Excel.Application
    Set ExcelApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    ExcelApp.Workbooks.Open "YourWorkBookLocation"
    
    ExcelApp.Run "MacroName"
    
    ExcelApp.Quit
    Set ExcelApp = Nothing
```

The child could then write to a text file and the parent would be waiting for it in a loop (make sure to use Sleep for the Windows API to reduce CPU usage).

You could even consider using multi-threading if your algorithm supports that by creating multiple instances of Excel that run in parallel. (See also [this Analyst's Cave article](https://analystcave.com/excel-vba-multithreading-tool/) on the topic).

---

However, if you really need to run this on a server you could consider paying for a web-hosting service that supports Windows. Otherwise, I would recommend porting the VBA code to a similar language that can more easily be run in a container like VBScript, VB6, TwinBASIC or even VB.NET.

Comment: Thank you, I found out that I dont need a server at all. I can do it everything by Excel itself.